# Ruby Hash from Sage Pay response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, split

I have a response `@response` from Sage Pay:

```
VPSProtocol=2.23 Status=OK StatusDetail=Server transaction registered successfully. VPSTxId={C9B14A59-1EB7-4A56-A4B1-29B84BE4861B} SecurityKey=VGGPR12XC1 NextURL=https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPServerPaymentPage.asp?TransactionID={C9B14A59-1EB7-4A56-A4B1-XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

How can I split this into a hash of:

```
@response['VPSProtocol'] = "2.23"
@response['Status'] = "OK"
....
```

?

(Params in the response are newline separate `\r\n`)

Comment: You mean something like the [String scan example on the Rails documentation](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001552)

Comment: @matthewnreid I would just like to access each individual param that was returned, instead of having a string of new-line separated values.

Comment: This isn't really a Rails questions, it's nothing specific to Rails at all ;)

Comment: @tarnfeld I have updated the title in response to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
response = "VPSProtocol=2.23\r\nStatus=OK\r\nStatusDetail=Server transaction registered successfully."
response_hash = {}

response.split("\r\n").map do |value|
  key, value = value.split("=")
  response_hash[key] = value
end

print response_hash
```

I'm sure there's a handy method in ruby to do this kind of mapping, but thats a quick solution. Would love to hear some better ideas from the community!